# How to make swagger to handle wrappers with generics like Flux<T>?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

i have a controller method (spring-boot) that returns

```
fun controlerMethod(): Flux<MyPojo>
```

how to configure swagger to treat the return type as `List<MyPojo>`? And `Mono<MyPojo>` as `MyPojo`? Is it possible to do some global configuration or i have to mark every single controller function with `@ApiResponse`?

Comment: Are you using spring webflux ?

Comment: no, i couldn't make swagger work with webflux. using mvc with flux and mono types